# Bluetooth low energy - multiple TI sensor Tags connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

is it possible to connect multiple sensor tags via Bluetooth low energy? In the app provided by TI, the sensor tag is the server, and app is client. So, it is possible for a single client to connect multiple servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'm using the same chipset and have been able to connect 7 devices with one Bluetooth dongle.  The limitation is dependent on the bluetooth hardware you're using (I had one dongle that only allowed 3 connections at once).

Comment: Thank you! I am new to android programming. In you scenario, is the dongle server, and chipsets are clients? Did you use thread for BluetoothService?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with which half is client and which is server with Bluetooth...  The sensors are running GATT which is like a server and the dongle on the machine is making queries like a client.  I'm not using Android, so I don't know what BluetoothService is.